# Suggest OOP analysis/design - break my procedural habits

Tags: python, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I would like to use OOP/OOD as an exercise for a small project, but I often find myself using a procedural approach when coding. I use Python in combination with Flask (web framework)

In essence my app is a kind of spider that reads an rss feed for new movie releases. For each new movie release it uses the imdb link to gather information from two different web services (imdbapi and TMDb) regarding plot, year, genre, poster and info like that. If the preferred service cannot provide the information, then use the other service. 
Finally save all the info in a db. 
I then use Flask to present the information on a website

I have created a Spider class for now. It contains the following methods (code removed for clarity):

```
class Spider():
""" Spider Class """

def __init__(self, rssfeed):

def run_update(self):
    movie_list = self.get_entries_from_feed()
    self.get_imdb_json(movie_list)

def get_entries_from_feed(self):
    """ reads an rss feed and return a list of lists with imdb id, title, and added date         time """

def get_imdb_json(self, movie_list):
    """ get json data from imdbapi based on list with imdb id"""
    if not in db:
        save_to_db

def save_to_db(self, key, nzb_title, added, data):
    """ save entry to db from json data"""
```

The "problem" is that I use the **run_update()** method to carry out all the steps in a procedural way. I also find the design inflexible. E.g if I can't get movie information for one service i'd like to try the other service, but this is not very easy to implement in the current format.

What I have thought about is to create a Movie class, representing each movie found in the rssfeed. Maybe also to create classes for each of the services I use for gathering information about each movie, imdbapi and TMDb?

So, how would you go about and design an app like this in an OOP/OOD fashion? I find it a little hard to identify classes, when we are beyond the simple examples used in text books - like cars, books, fruits and etc.

Comment: Not a solution, but a general suggestion on OO. I've always found using (so called) "real world" examples like cars e.t.c. when explaining OO just about as confusing as using bags to explain sets. If you make sure not apply the individual solutions too dogmatically you might want to look up some tutorial/book on design patterns; I remember finding at least some of them quite enlightening examples of how the kind of polymorphism used by OO systems can help you express the points at which your program can change and allow you to change the behaviour of your program in a modular fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of Python is that it supports many different programming paradigms in a very seamless way. Don't worry so much about doing everything in OOP, use the right tool for the job. Not everything is a nail so don't limit yourself to just a hammer.

Having said that, if you are just wanting an exercise in OOP, look for patterns. For instance, a Strategy Pattern might be a good solution for your multiple sources of information. I highly recommend the [GoF Patterns book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) to anyone wanting to get a better handle on OOP. It should be required reading IMHO for anyone wanting to move beyond basic programming.

For discovering objects, the classic approach is to start looking for nouns in your problem space and make those  your objects: movie, feed, imdb, tmdb. Then you start thinking about what attributes and functionality should be associated with each object (adjectives and verbs if you want to continue the analogy). When you start seeing common functionality, like you should with imdb and tmdb, then you might consider a common base class: mdb. The next step is to look at relationships between objects. I'm a visual person so I always make a [Class Diagram](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classDiagram.htm) to help me understand relationships. Read up on [CRC Cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-responsibility-collaboration_card) and [Responsibility-Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility-Driven_Design) for more details on this technique.

If you have some basic working knowledge of the common patterns, how they work and where they apply, you will start to notice patterns in your objects. If not, this technique will still help you build useful OO systems. The risk is that you might be reinventing the wheel or your might miss something that could save you a lot of time later.

Comment: Have been reading up on the Strategy Pattern and it seems like a good approach to this problem.

Comment: @happygoat, I added more detail about discovering objects and behaviors. Hope that helps as well.

Comment: thanks for the additional info. Regarding the Strategy Pattern it is actually invisible in Python due to first-class functions, as you probably know. [The Lack of Design Patterns in Python](http://bitworking.org/news/428/the-lack-of-design-patterns-in-python-pycon-2009)

Comment: Yes, python makes many things trivial that require a lot more effort in other languages -- like he says, the patterns are generally built into the language. But it doesn't invalidate the use of patterns.

Answer (score 1):

To do OOP you need to identify each problem you need to solve, and then solve it independently of the others problem (That way you'll obtain all the nice SOLID, etc... benefits from OOP).

Most people will probably call me an extremist (and they'll probably be right), but this approach works extremely well for me:

I've identified these problems, so I'd create a class for each one of those. Then you'll need to "bind" them, thinking not about how you'll accomplish what you want to do, but instead focusing of what you want to do, and trying to leave the "implementation details", always for "later" (or deeper) for as long as you can:

```
run_update
    get entries from feed
        obtain the feed
        read the feed
        parse an movie entry
            manage movie entry information
    get imdb json
        talking with imdbapi
        parsing json 
        converting json to movie
        talking with db
            querying the db
            saving with db
                convert movie to db format
```

Comment: You wite: "I've identified these problems, so I'd create a class for each one of those"....to clarify: Would you create a class for run_update, get_entries_from_feed and get_imdb_json? Thanks

Comment: Yeap, that's about 14 classes right there... In my experience, making a lot of extremely cohesive classes with only a single responsibility and only a few methods and variables work extremely well, and helps produce great designs. My methods usually have 2 to 5 (short) lines...

Comment: I really can't imagine a need for so many classes for such a simple example. I think you are confusing objects (aka classes) with methods.

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking that! My approach would be to create classes for Feed, MovieService with subclasses TmdbService, ImdbService and a Movie class. Handling of db is done by SQL-Alchemy in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ORM like SQLAlchemy for your tracking and populating your models/persistent data and the relationships between them. Thats the primary OOP thing you can do with a typical web app.

Dont do OOP just for the sake of OOP however. Another good way is to find where you have duplicated code/logic and try to refactor it into one place. Try to make each class decoupled and not know about how other classes are implemented. Think of things in terms of public APIs and contracts. This usually leads to OOP design.

Comment: I know you cannot see it from my question, but I am using SQLAlchemy as ORM and a SQLite db as backend for storing the movies with related information, plot, rating, votes etc.